# using union to join different queries with different group by

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have different queries (3), which have different conditions to obtain different counters.

In 2 of them, the grouping is the same, but in one of them no.

Count lines picking

```
select 
carusrrsppck as 'users', 
COUNT(carusrrsppck) AS 'lines picking', 
cardepid as 'deposit'  
from order_products
where DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, carfchcar)) 
between '20190220' and '20190220' 
and cardepid in ('D32', 'DA', 'DA1', 'DB', 'DC', 'DD', 'DE', 'DR')
and carusrrsppck<>''
and ordprdcnt<>0
group by carusrrsppck, cardepid
order by cardepid, COUNT(*) DESC
```

Count lines denied

```
select carusrrsppck as 'users', 
COUNT(carusrrsppck) as 'lines denied',
cardepid as 'deposit'
from order_products
where DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, carfchcar)) 
between '20190220' and '20190220' 
and ordprdcnt=0
and cardepid in ('D32', 'DA', 'DA1', 'DB', 'DC', 'DD', 'DE', 'DR')
and carusrrsppck<>''
group by carusrrsppck, cardepid
order by cardepid, COUNT(*) DESC
```

Count lines confirmed

```
select 
carusrcar as 'user', 
COUNT(carusrcar) as 'lines confirmed',
cardepid as 'deposit' 
from order_products 
where DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, carfchcar)) 
between '20190220' and '20190220' 
and cardepid in ('D32', 'DA', 'DA1', 'DB', 'DC', 'DD', 'DE', 'DR')
group by carusrcar, cardepid
order by cardepid, COUNT(*) DESC
```

Is possible to join the 3 queries even though they are grouped differently, or I can only join those that have the same "group by"?

Thanks.

Comment: As long as they have the same number and type of columns, you can indeed UNION them.  Note that, by default, a UNION statement only returns distinct results (if that matters).  The syntax would be "<first select> UNION <second select> UNION <third select>".

Comment: Excellent point @BoCoKeith - rows with "lines picking" matching "lines denied" for the same carusrrsppck will get de-duped which could throw off your expected results. Best to add an additional column indicating what the resultset is (e.g. `SELECT rsType = 'Lines Picking', carusrrsppck as 'usres', COUNT(*) ...`)

Comment: @Forty3 yes, i need add an additional column for each count. In this case, should separates in subqueries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Count lines picking` and `Count lines denied` queries use the same grouping columns and differ only in the conditions, so they could be simplified to this:

```
SELECT 
  carusrrsppck as 'users', 
  SUM(CASE WHEN carusrrsppck <> '' and ordprdcnt <> 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'lines picking', 
  SUM(CASE WHEN carusrrsppck <> '' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'lines denied',
  cardepid AS 'deposit'  
FROM order_products
WHERE 
  DATEADD(dd, 0, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, carfchcar)) BETWEEN '20190220' and '20190220' 
  AND 
  cardepid IN ('D32', 'DA', 'DA1', 'DB', 'DC', 'DD', 'DE', 'DR')
GROUP BY carusrrsppck, cardepid
ORDER BY cardepid, COUNT(*) DESC
```

The `Count lines confirmed` query is a different case and can't be associated to the above.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select carusrrsppck as users, 
       cardepid as deposit  
       sum(case when carusrrsppck <> '' and ordprdcnt <> 0 then 1 else 0 end) AS lines_picking, 
       sum(case when carusrrsppck <> '' and ordprdcnt = 0 then 1 else 0 end) AS lines_denied, 
       count(*) as lines_confirmed
from order_products
where carfchar >= '20190220' and 
      carfchar < '20190221' and
      cardepid in ('D32', 'DA', 'DA1', 'DB', 'DC', 'DD', 'DE', 'DR')
group by carusrrsppck, cardepid
order by cardepid, COUNT(*) DESC;
```

Note:  The date arithmetic is better without the conversion.  The above should be equivalent to what you have.

Also, don't use single quotes for column aliases.  Instead, choose column names that do not need to be escaped.